# mysql UPDATE only if exists NO INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I wonder if there is no short way to update a row only if a key exists. I dont want to insert a new row otherwise, so INSERT ON DPULICATE KEY is not working.

For example:

I have a table containing addresses of lets say 200 customer with an primary key on their unique customer id. Now I get a new excel list of 500 addresses containing their updated data. I want to update all of the 200 customers in my table but I dont want to add the 300 other ones.

So I search for something like

UPDATE ON EXISTS

All searches for this keywords lead to INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE. So I hope you can help.

Comment: I may be missing the point, but isn't it as simple as "update master, addr set mastercol = addrcol where idmaster = idaddr"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use another way.

for example:

> 1. insert the 500 customer into a new table.
> 2. use nature join to update the 200 customer info.

then you can use update like :

```
update A set A.address = B.address where A.id = B.id;
```

then drop the B table.